# How correctly install JRE/JDK for Java application and verify it

Tags: java, windows-server-2012-r2

I'm trying to set up a box on Windows Server 2012 R2, 64. Tried to install legacy 3rd party vendor Java application and can't make it work, they said it works ok on Java 8+, but need help with installation.
I pasted screenshot, I'm confused should I  get new folder JRE after running and successfully installing jre-9u231, don't see it.  -version command also gave me not good result. Hope you can see all info on pic pasted below.

I'm actually db guy, don't have handy people around for Java, trying to see if I'm moving to the right direction. Should I change something in Registry,  or Java section in COntrol Panel.

Java Setup:
[image: Java Setup]

Adding most more info from Cmd line afer adding JAVA to path:

```
C:\Users\rosokov>echo %java_home%
C:\Program Files (x86)\Java\jdk1.8.0_151

C:\Users\rosokov>java -version
Error: opening registry key 'Software\JavaSoft\JRE'
Error: could not find java.dll
Error: Could not find Java SE Runtime Environment.

C:\Users\rosokov>where java
C:\Users\rosokov\java
C:\Program Files (x86)\Common Files\Oracle\Java\javapath\java.exe
C:\ProgramData\Oracle\Java\javapath\java.exe
C:\Program Files (x86)\Java\jdk1.8.0_151\bin\java.exe
```

and here my updated PATH from SET with added

```
;C:\Program Files (x86)\Java\jdk1.8.0_151\bin



     ALLUSERSPROFILE=C:\ProgramData
        APPDATA=C:\Users\vrosokov\AppData\Roaming
        CLASSPATH=C:\reports\sqljdbc_6.2\enu\mssql-jdbc-6.2.2.jre8.jar

OS=Windows_NT
Path=C:\Program Files (x86)\Common Files\Oracle\Java\javapath;C:\ProgramData\Oracle\Java\javapath;C:\Windows\system32;C:\Windows;C:\Windows\System32\Wbem;C:\Windows\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\;C:\Program Files\Microsoft\Web Platform Installer\;C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft ASP.NET\ASP.NET Web Pages\v1.0\;C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\8.0\Windows Performance Toolkit\;C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\120\Tools\Binn\;C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SQL Server\110\Tools\Binn\ManagementStudio\;C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SQL Server\110\Tools\Binn\;C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 11.0\Common7\IDE\PrivateAssemblies\;C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SQL Server\110\DTS\Binn\;C:\REPORTS\sqljdbc_6.2\enu;C:\Program Files (x86)\Java\jdk1.8.0_151\bin
PATHEXT=.COM;.EXE;.BAT;.CMD;.VBS;.VBE;.JS;.JSE;.WSF;.WSH;.MSC
```

Comment: What does the PATH say?

Comment: HiScratte! Pasted PATH. TX. Should I add Java_Home to Path?

Comment: Java JDK 8 folder is not in your path

Comment: use your java_home path plus `/bin`

Comment: Yes, I usually add it like this `%JAVA_HOME%\bin`

Comment: and also, maybe you need to download the server version of the installer: https://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/downloads/server-jre8-downloads-2133154.html

Comment: Tx all, I'm adding %JAVA_HOME%\bin to PATH.

Comment: can you see my pic, JAVA_HOME set to C:\Program Files (x86)\Java\jdk1.8.0_151.  is this right dir ? should I have /bin ?

Comment: Tx all again!  Java guys are really really nice !!!! Need to get a break for kids. Will keep posting my results. Dz!

Comment: yes you should have `\bin`

Comment: ooh, I just noticed, you have other oracle products installed on your machine which may be causing path issues. Move the jre/jdk path configuration to before the oracle java path configuration... before this one `C:\Program Files (x86)\Common Files\Oracle\Java\javapath` like `PATH=C:\Program Files (x86)\Java\jdk1.8.0_151\bin;C:\Program Files (x86)\Common Files\Oracle\Java\javapath......`

Comment: @JorgeCampos I never did that. I always just put it at the end.

Comment: The `JAVA_HOME` should not have the `\bin`, but the `PATH` has to have it included. That's why I just add it like `;%JAVA_HOME%\bin`. I switch between my java installations, and I just change the `JAVA_HOME` variable when I do it and leave the `PATH` as it is.

Comment: Unless you have the absolute need and a license you should dump Oracle Java. Download AdoptOpenJdk 8 or 11, extract the archive (no install needed) and set the env like described above

Comment: Try to move the path up, like @JorgeCampos suggested.

Comment: Thanks all, after moving JAVA_HOME up, it worked OK, @Jorge thanks for Server Version, for now it works fine with what I have, and this server version is just folder on exec files, just need copy/configure, is this right ?

Comment: I would assume so.